# unsigned integer in c

Tags: c

Given a program like below how to identify that whether the signed integer will go to a -ve or +value.

```
int main()
{
    int a=0xDEADBEEF;
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs in -ve.But is there any easy way to identify it quickly without executing in visual studio.

Comment: Do you mean you want to recognize whether the printed integer is positive or negative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With some bitwise magic:

```
int negative = (input >> ((sizeof(int) * 8) - 1)) & 0x01;
```

To explain it:

In C, negative numbers are two's-complement, where the highest bit denotes the sign. We first determine how many bits an `int` has on the current platform using `sizeof(int) * 8`. To get the highest bit via right shift, we need to shift by `size - 1`. As the right shift is arithmetical in C (meaning if the highest bit is `1`, we fill the int with `1`s from the left on), we need to kill all extra bits using logical and with `0x01` (or simply `1`, whatever you prefer).

The result is an `int` with value `1` if the input is negative, or `0` if it is positive.

If you want to do it on paper, take the highbyte (in your case, `DE`), write out the upper half (`D`) and check wether the highbit of that is a zero or one.

Comment: ...that still requires compiling and running.

Comment: You can also do it on paper, which is even easier than your solution as you don't have to write out the whole number.

Comment: "right shift is arithmetical in C". It's implementation-defined. It's also implementation-defined whether negative numbers are two's complement, whether the number of bits in a `char` is 8, and whether `int` has padding bits. The answers to those things are the same pretty much everywhere, but you shouldn't really say "in C, X is true" unless it's actually guaranteed by the standard.

Answer (score 3):

See if the value is less than 0x80, 0x8000, 0x80000000, or 0x8000000000000000, depending on the bit depth of the type. If it is less than then it's positive, otherwise it's negative.

Answer (score 1):

If the first bit (sign bit) is 1, then the value is negative. Otherwise it is positive.

BTW, there is one more negative number compared with amount of the positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to know the width (number of value bits) in `int` to decide on that.

You'd also have to give a `\n` at the end of your format string to be sure to have an output.

Answer (score 0):

`0xDEADBEEF` is larger than `INT_MAX` on your system (`0x7FFFFFFF`), so the conversion to `int` is implementation-defined. Common twos complement implementations define it as reduction modulo `2*INT_MAX+2` into the range `[INT_MIN,INT_MAX]`.